# Add specific/manual user consent to Microsoft Graph in ASP.Net Core (Blazor)

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, blazor-server-side

I have a web application build in Blazor (ASP.NET Core). The application is multi-tenant and I need to control who has access, thus I use my own user database (DefaultIdentity) stored in an SQL database.

Now I need access to Microsoft Graph (for some of the users). I have this working by using application level access, but would like to avoid having to have the local IT admin set this up in their Azure AD - and I want to adhere to the "least privilege principle".

So I would like to be able to add a sign-in page/functionality where a specific user (after they have logged on using my local user database) can give my app autorization+consent to retrieve Calendar.Read permission through Microsoft Graph.

How would I do this? Can I invoke ad azure sign-in/consent page programatically from my web application? (Probably) - but how?

Comment: Hmm, essentially you need to redirect the user to the sign in endpoint with scope "Calendar.Read". This should prompt consent from them for that. Do note that then authentication needs to be done with per-user access tokens, and you need to handle refresh tokens too.

Answer (score 0):

You are using application level access. So I think you are following [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) rather than [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user).

In this case, you can not grant `Calendar.Read` application permission using a specific user because this permission requires admin consent and it takes effect on the full tenant.

So this design is not very appropriate.

[image]

What you need to do is to configure an application access policy and limit the scope of application permissions.

See details here: [Scoping application permissions to specific Exchange Online mailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access).

I know you don't want to configure it using from AAD, but it's the best way and you don't need to limit the scope from your code.

Comment: Thank you. This is a possibility in order to adhere to "least privilege principle".
Although I would still need to get the customer internal IT to perform the setup.

Comment: @MichaelØsterbergJakobsen For application permission (not delegated permission), I believe you cannot use the design what you have expected. If my answer is helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you.